# MVC Saving ActionResult to byte array

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for a good way to save an MVC ActionResult to a byte array (file). Reason for this is that I'm using Rotativa to convert a HTML View to a PDF. That works nicely and returns my user with the PDF in the browser. Now I want to send an e-mail from the server, including that same PDF as an attachment. For sending e-mail I'm using the ActionMailer.Net nuget package. That has the option of including byte arrays as attachments.

So I need to pass a byte array with my PDF file to the send mail method. But the action returning the PDF has ActionResult as returntype, not FileStreamResult (unfortunately). I don't exactly know why this choice was made, but that's what it is.

The Rotativa package uses Wkhtmltopdf to convert the HTML. I guess I could implement that myself, but that seems kinda pointless since I already have a method which returns exactly what I need; I just need a way to get that result into a byte array.

Comment: Wow I am just going through the exact same issue with Rotativa and wanting to email a PDF too and just found your thread... I ended up thinking that I need to save the ActionResult as a stream as well.. It's the far easiest option I think because the other PDF libraries are way too complicated/messy and overkill. Rotativa just works..

Answer (score 6):

You can inherit 'ViewAsPdf' and create a method to call some protected methods of 'ViewAsPdf':

```
public class ViewAsPdf2 : ViewAsPdf
{
    public ViewAsPdf2(string viewName, object model) : base(viewName, model) { }
    public byte[] GetByte(ControllerContext context)
    {
        base.PrepareResponse(context.HttpContext.Response);
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
        return base.CallTheDriver(context);
    }
}
```

And in your action:

```
var pdf = new ViewAsPdf2("MyView", model);
var pdfByteArray = pdf.GetByte(ControllerContext);
SendEmail(pdfByteArray);
return null;
```

So you can use the `byte[]` to do what you want and the return will be the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You could send an HTTP request to the controller action that is supposed to return the PDF and save the result as byte array. The [`WebClient.DownloadData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx) method seems appropriate.

If you want to preserve the context (Session, Authenticated User) you need to set the Cookie header:

```
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
```

Comment: Does that handle context? Logged in user, stuff like that?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You will have to provide the necessary cookies for the request. You could do this by setting the `client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie]` property before sending the request - `Request.Headers["Cookie"]`. This way you would transmit the context. I have updated my answer to provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, here's my solution:

You need to basically make a HTTP request to your own URL and save the output as a binary file. Simple as, no overload, helper classes and bloated stuff.

You'll need this method:

```
    // Returns the results of fetching the requested HTML page.
    public static void SaveHttpResponseAsFile(string RequestUrl, string FilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RequestUrl);
            httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)";
            httpRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                    response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
            }

            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                Stream FinalStream = responseStream;
                if (response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
                    FinalStream = new GZipStream(FinalStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
                else if (response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
                    FinalStream = new DeflateStream(FinalStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);

                using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(FilePath))
                {
                    FinalStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }

                response.Close();
                FinalStream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
```

Then inside your controller, you call it like this:

```
SaveHttpResponseAsFile("http://localhost:52515/Management/ViewPDFInvoice/" + ID.ToString(), "C:\\temp\\test.pdf");
```

And wala! The file is there on your file system and you can double click and open the PDF, or email it to your users, or whatever you need...